# pysnow 0.7.5 - How can I make a complex Query with 2 tables like in SQL?

Tags: python, servicenow

I'm using pysnow **0.7.5**.

I would like to extract a part of data from 2 **service now** tables ("**rm_defect**" and "**u_cmdb_ci_appl_entreprise**" )

These tables are linked by **u_cmdb_ci_appl_entreprise.sys_id=rm_defect.u_application.value**

How can I make a complex Query with this 2 tables like in SQL?
Something like that:

```
  qb = (
    pysnow.QueryBuilder()
    .field('rm_defect.number').contains('ANO01234')
    .AND()
    .field('rm_defect.u_application.value').equals('u_cmdb_ci_appl_entreprise.sys_id')
     )
```

Here is my source

```
import pysnow 
import os

instance='XXXX' user='XXXX' password='XXXX'

c = pysnow.Client(instance=instance, user=user, password=password)

# List of defects defectResource = c.resource(api_path='/table/rm_defect')

qb = (
    pysnow.QueryBuilder()
    .field('number').contains('ANO01234') )

defectRecords = defectResource.get(query=qb,stream=True)

print('rm_defect:') for defectRecord in defectRecords.all():
        number = str(defectRecord['number'])
        state = str(defectRecord['state'])
        if (isinstance(defectRecord['u_application'], dict)): 
            application = defectRecord['u_application']['value']
        else:
            application = ""
        print('number '+number)
        print('state '+state)
        print('application '+application)
        print('------------')


# List of applications appResource = c.resource(api_path='/table/u_cmdb_ci_appl_entreprise')

qb = (
    pysnow.QueryBuilder()
    .field('name').equals('appli1') )

appRecords = appResource.get(query=qb)

for appRecord in appRecords.all():
        sys_id = str(appRecords['sys_id'])
        name = str(appRecords['name'])
        print('sys_id '+sys_id)
        print('name '+name)
        print('------------')
```

Here is the result

```
number ANO01234
state 15
application 551de62ddbe02e80e478751bbf9619b0
------------
sys_id 551de62ddbe02e80e478751bbf9619b0
name appli1
------------
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create view, that will contain these two tables and then run the query against that view instead of the individual tables.

System Definition => Database Views [sys_db_view]

For example you can have a look at view covering incident and task_sla that has name `incident_sla`. Please note the Variable prefix column. It is important in querying the view. Such view can be queried in the following way.

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident_sla');
gr.setLimit(10);
gr.query();

while(gr.next()) {
    gs.print(gr.getValue('inc_number') + ' ---- ' + gr.getDisplayValue('taskslatable_sla'));
}
```

This script will return `number` from the incident table and `sla` from task_sla table.